# Graph API GET "filesFolder" failing "Folder location for this channel is not ready yet, please try again later"

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

So after creating a channel in MS Team, I am making a graph API call -> GET /teams/{id}/channels/{id}/filesFolder

Because, I want the drive Id, for creation of folders inside the channel. But this API is failing

```
{
"error": {
"code": "NotFound",
"message": "Folder location for this channel is not ready yet, please try again later.",
"innerError": {
"date": "2021-03-22T13:01:23",
"request-id": "Not mentioning id here",
"client-request-id": "Not mentioning id here"
}
}
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to get filesFloder right after the channel creation? In the next run again are you able to get the results?

Comment: In the last week yes. just after channel creation I was able to get those filesFolder info. But now it is taking lot of time. Today, I created a channel manually in teams and went to files tab , it was showing : "We can't get your files We're working on getting them back."

Answer (score 1):

If you make a first request to "General" Team channel files folder, then works for other channels:

```
Get-PnPTeamsChannelFilesFolder -Team $TeamName -Channel "General
```

You can use Graph API too.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a channel, it won't create a files folder in share-point. You need to go to channel and chick on files tab to create a files folder in share point. Teams create the files folder in share pint on Demand. This is by design. Could you please try going to channel  in UI and redirecting to files tab and then check the folder using Graph API?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Even if I go to a channel's files tab. It asks me to wait for sometime. But still we want it to be completely automated. the issue is intermittent sometimes we get info, sometimes don't. but I don't how much time I need to wait before making this call

Comment: It willl take some time to update, Could  you please try after 24 hours?